# Can you tell who am I?

Tags: riddle

***This is my first riddle on this site.***

**Riddle :** The more you take, the more you leave behind. What am I?

Hint:

> A thing you do everyday.

Comment: Please mention the source where you took this riddle from.

Comment: Why?? Is it an offence. :-(

Comment: No, no. It's not an offence, but it is site's [policy](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism).

Comment: from here: [This site](http://www.doriddles.com/riddle-38#show)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

> Footsteps. Obviously more footsteps we take, the more we leave behind.

Comment: Unless you walk backward

Answer (score 2):

The more you take, the more you leave behind?

First one was

## FOOD

And second one is

## TOILET PAPER(EDITED)

Comment: I was going to say toilet paper ahahah

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> Footsteps.

It is an easily google-able riddle...